# How to remove a line based on a regular expression with exceptions

Tags: regex, string, regular-language

I need to remove lines that have the following characteristics.

```
<img src="index-1_2.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-1_3.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-1_5.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-2_1.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-2_5.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-3_1.png"/><br>
<img src="index-23_8.png"/><br>
<img src="index-22_9.png"/><br>
<img src="index-22_1.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-22_2.jpg"/><br>
<img src="index-99_5.png"/><br>
<img src="index-100_5.png"/><br>
<img src="index-1000_5.png"/><br>
...
```

As you can see, the number that is found after the word **index** and after the _ and also, the image format (png, jpg) varies.

I need to generate a regex that removes all these lines **EXECPTING** numbers found after the **index**. For example, I need to keep the lines that have only the numbers 1 and 2.

I have the following generated regular expression

```
^<img src="index-(?!2|1)\d+_\d+\.(?:jpg|png)"\/><br>$
```

but wanting to keep the numbers 1 and 2, it also keeps the numbers 22, 23, 100 and 1000 since they contain those numbers

Comment: Why did you accept the answer which simply copied my answer, rather than accept my answer?

Comment: because the answer was more descriptive and shared the full regex instead, though it posted the correct answer but I didn't find the how to implement it correctly.

Comment: "...but I didn't find the how to implement it correctly". You need to improve the question - state what programming language you are using and show how you are trying to make the replacement etc. And remove those silly 'string' and  'regular-language' tags. And if you are going to use a bold capitalised word in your question then you should at least spell it correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^<img src="index-(?![12]_)(\d+)_\d+\.(?:jpg|png)"\/><br>$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/8dogmk/2). Use `$1` as replacement.

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <img src="index-         '<img src="index-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [12]                     any character of: '1', '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jpg                      'jpg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    png                      'png'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ><br>                    '><br>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the exception section of numbers

Comment: @None Sorry, added.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the negative lookahead `(?!2|1)` you could use

```
(?![12]_)
```

which prevents a match if the next character is 1 or 2 followed by an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

By fiddling around [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_regex_seq1), I think I got what you are looking for:

```
import re

txt = "index-4_8.jpg"
txt2 = "index-1_8.png"

#Check if the string starts with "The":

x = re.search("^(index-2_|index-1_).+(.jpg|.png)$", txt)

if (x):
    print('Matched')
else:
    print('NotMatched')

x = re.search("^(index-2_|index-1_).+(.jpg|.png)$", txt2)

if (x):
    print('Matched')
else:
    print('NotMatched')
```